# 20.04 LTS can't install error "Newbie" Openvpn

Tags: apt, updates, openvpn

I'm getting the following error:

```
Skipping acquire of configured file 'fossa/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'fossa' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

one of 11 error lines same for 64

Comment: How do you get this output? How is this related to OpenVPN? What changes did you do to the system. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1367716/edit) to add these information.

Comment: apt update openvpn3   I changed nothing

Comment: W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'fossa/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'fossa' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Comment: I am not sure why you entered the same output in the question in a comment once again, please let me know if my answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the following command to install openvpn.

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```

If the issue persists, you'll need to replace your software sources.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
```

And then install openvpn with the first command.

Comment: thank you .. i'm trying

Comment: doesn't have the component 'fossa' (component misspelt in sources.list?) -- can I change the word ? my system don't know "fossa" ?

Comment: `fossa` is not supposed to be in the sources.list. It is focal, not fossa. Are you still getting the same issue after replacing the sources.list? Did you execute the last four commands.